# PHPExcel File Last Modified Date

Tags: phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to read a remote file which is hosted on a public dropbox folder.

How can I get the file's last modified date and time?

Comment: Load the spreadsheet file, and then use `$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->getModified()` should return the last modified value

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!!